# Squares-for-linebreaks missing in List view control. Why? .NET

Tags: c#, .net, listview

This is not particularly a programming question, but I was hoping someone here may know the answer.

We have in-house written application in C#. It's uses ListView control (i believe) to display a list of items - items/text that contains line breaks (newline chars). On most PCs (WinXP) the line breaks are displayed as two square characters. But on one particular PC the boxes are not displayed at all, and two lines are concatenated together without any visual separation..

Does anyone knows why would that be?
Is that controlled by some setting in OS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vadim is correct. The two squares are the current fonts substitution for non-printable characters. I'm not sure what you are doing in your app, but I would probably strip out the cr and lf characters before storing or displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

I would check default font on that machine.  If you need to see how to check or change default font, read  [Fonts - Change Default article](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/106279-fonts-change-default.html).

**Update:**
You can also try to restore default font.  I just found this this article that explains [how to restore default Windows XP Fonts](http://www.hwdot.com/how-to-restore-default-windows-xp-fonts/).

Comment: Thanks, Vadim, but that doesn't seems to be it. there's no FontSubstitutes on that machine (or others I've checked, for that matter). Besides, fonts appear to be the same on our machines.